# In a SQL AG system, how can I have users input data to one node’s databases, while the other node is undergoing schema/table changes?

Tags: sql-server, architecture, high-availability, system-administration

Not sure if this is possible, but I’m looking to achieve zero downtime upgrades for our set of applications. We have a custom application that users use to connect to a set of services that transfer data on the backend to various Microsoft SQL databases. When we do software upgrades, the databases undergo various schema/table changes that cause application errors if you’re using the app while this maintenance is being done. I’m wondering if we’d be able to route users to use one SQL node that is not being upgraded while we upgrade the other SQL node’s databases, and merge changes from both nodes with zero or limited downtime so that we don’t have data loss for users that input the data or for the application update.

It seems like a stretch or perhaps a pipe dream but if anyone has any ideas I’m all ears!

Comment: You can remove one replica from the availability group and update that one while everybody accesses the other one. That would allow you to keep going during the downtime, but when you tried to add it back into the group you would have a schema mismatch.

Comment: For "zero" downtime you'd need to remove the database(s) from the AG, deploy the changes, take a full backup and re-add them to the AG.

Comment: Ideally you make schema changes that are backward compatible and don't break the app. Adding a column, dropping a column, adding parameters to a stored procedure, renaming anything, adding a table, dropping a table, most of these can be done independently of changing the app. [Some ideas here](https://sqlblog.org/?s=database+changes+compatible+backward+when).